# Cloud Function to copy all the files from a Storage bucket to a folder inside the same GCS storage bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have files inside a Google Cloud Storage bucket, I want to copy all the files from the bucket as received and create a copy of all those files inside a folder in the same bucket.
(I found solution to copy to a bucket, but how to copy to a FOLDER inside a bucket?)

`destination = storage_client.bucket('source-bucket-name')` #here my source & destination bucket is same

Is there a way to pass the folder name along with the bucket name?

Answer (score 3):

Actually Google Cloud Storage does not have genuine "folders". In the Cloud Storage console, the files in your bucket are presented in a hierarchical tree of folders (just like the file system on your local hard disk) but this is just a way of presenting the files: there aren't genuine folders/directories in a bucket. The Cloud Storage console just uses the different parts of the file paths to "simulate" a folder structure, by using the "/" delimiter character.

This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) on Cloud Storage and gsutil explains and illustrates very well this "illusion of a hierarchical file tree".

So, in other words, it's up to you to use a **file name** (or file path) that is composed by the "folder/directory" name, then the "/" delimiter character and finally the file name. E.g.: `fileName = "summer1970/pic1234.jpg"`. As clarified in the comments below, the illusion of a hierarchical file tree is created via the files naming not via the bucket naming.

Comment: ok, so does it mean that I can directly pass the folderName with bucket name? eg: destination = storage_client.bucket('source-bucket-name/folderName') - @Renaud Tarnec

Comment: No, not at all. There is only one bucket which is `storage_client.bucket('source-bucket-name')`, since you wrote "my source & destination bucket is same". In this bucket you create **files** and when you define the file name you can use the "/" delimiter character to mimic a folder structure. So the illusion of a hierarchical file tree is created **via the files naming** not via the bucket naming. If you share your entire code I can point you where to adapt.