# Invalid Bucket Name when uploading to Firebase storage?

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a media (Image) to firebase storage. Bucket Path is

```
gs://sample-ccc80.appspot.com/SAMPLE/IMAGES
```

Firebase Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write;
}
}
}
```

I am following this [blog](https://medium.com/teamarimac/file-upload-and-download-with-spring-boot-firebase-af068bc62614) as a tutorial. Here is the response I am getting:

```
"message" : "Invalid bucket name: 'sample-ccc80.appspot.com/SAMPLE/IMAGES'"
```

#code

```
 public static String uploadFile(File file, String fileName, String bucketName) throws IOException {
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, fileName);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("media").build();
    String absolutePath = "/service-account.json";
    Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(absolutePath));
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
    storage.create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
    String DOWNLOAD_URL  = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" + bucketName + "/o/%s?alt=media";
    return String.format(DOWNLOAD_URL, URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"));
}
```

What Am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

A Cloud Storage bucket name cannot contain a `/` (slash), see the [doc on "Bucket naming guidelines"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets).

I guess that you want to upload to the `SAMPLE/IMAGES` "folder" of your bucket, but Google Cloud Storage does not have genuine "folders" as explained in this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66655114/3371862).

You need to use the `fileName` variable to pass this "folder" like `SAMPLE/IMAGES/MyHolidaysNicePicture.png`. And your bucket name should be `gs://sample-ccc80.appspot.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After changing the bucket name to `gs://sample-ccc80.appspot.com`. I am still getting the same error message

Answer (score 0):

The bucket path that you have used is as follows:

```
gs://sample-ccc80.appspot.com/SAMPLE/IMAGES
```

According to guidelines available [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets) a Cloud Storage bucket name cannot contain a '/' sign that's why the part:

```
/SAMPLE/IMAGES
```

of your bucket's path is invalid.

Whatsmore, your bucket name should not contain the prefix `gs://`.

**Solution**:

Summing up, your bucket name should be as follows:

```
sample-ccc80.appspot.com
```

**P.S.**

For those who will be looking for the bucket's name of their project it can be found here:
[image: backet_name_location]